Determine the function:$ f : \mathbb R \to\mathbb R$
the question
Determine the function:$ f :\mathbb  R \to\mathbb R$ with the property:
$$f\left(x+\frac{a}{b}\right) \leq bx \leq f(x)+a$$
for any real number $x,$ where $a$ and $b$ are strictly positive real numbers.
The idea
Trying some possible values of the function I concluded that $f(x)=bx-a$ makes the equality case and it is one of the looked values. I don't know if this helps but is the only thing thatcame into my mind. I hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

Do you have any assumptions on $f$? Are $a$ and $b$ constant?

do you know about the differentiabilitty class of f?

Are $a,b$ fixed numbers?

@Math101 I think a and b are fixed...

@ThomasAndrews I think so

@LuizaCamile Sadly, nope

$f(x)=bx+a$ does not satisfy the problem. The first inequality isn't true for that $f.$

Let $a$,$b \in \mathbb R$ fixed.
First you have
$$bx\leq f(x)+a\iff  bx-a \leq f(x),\hspace{0.3cm }\forall x\in \mathbb R.$$
Also, denote $y=x+\frac{a}{b}$. Then $x=y-\frac{a}{b}$.
$$f(y)=f\left(x+\frac{a}{b}\right)\leq bx=b\left(y-\frac{a}{b}\right)=by-a \iff f(y)\leq by-a,\hspace{0.3cm}\forall y\in \mathbb R$$
Then
$$ f(x)=bx-a,\hspace{0.3cm} \forall x\in \mathbb R.$$

Thanks for your answer! May i ask if we can find the values of a or b?

@IONELABUCIU To find $a$ and $b$, you must be given at least two values of $f$ at given points $x$ and $y$ (There are other possible ways like knowing the value of the derivative, which is equal to $b$, and then having the value of $f$ at some other point, to find $a$).
