If we have $f(x)\geq bx-a$ and $f(y)\leq by-a$, for every x and y real numbers, this means that $f(x)=bx-a$?
If we have $f(x)\geq bx-a$ and $f(y)\leq by-a$, for every x and y real numbers, this means that $f(x)=bx-a$? How can I explain it? I need it to finish a problem... Thanks!

For context, can you include the problem you're trying to solve?

@V.S.e.H https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4904321/determine-the-function-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r

Since this is true for every real number x and y, in the second inequality, take y = x. You will get $f(x) \leq bx-a$ and from the first inequality you already have $f(x) \geq bx-a$ which implies $f(x) = bx-a$

Thanks for responding! But still, this is the only form that $f(x)$ can take? Sorry for this stupid questions, but I'm new into functions.

yes. the condition that you have given is very restricting. so this is the only form that f(x) can take. you can think it like this, for any x, the f(x) satisfies two very strict inequalities, so the value of f is completely determined for every real x, thus the form is concretely defined.
